# field within the object of array in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

The sample structure is as follows:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "College_name" : "abcdef"
    "Students": [
{
  "name": "a",
  "Grade": "First"
},
{
  "name": "b",
  "Grade": "Second"
},
{
  "name": "c",
  "Grade": "First"
},
{
  "name": "d",
  "Grade": "First"

}
]
}
```

What I am not getting is - I want to get all **("Grade" : "First")** objects in the array and insert only ("Grade" : "First") objects to other collection where **("College_name" : "abcdef")**. What is the optimal solution for this? 
Is this possible through aggregation??
Please help me out to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to this question is in the link:

[query to retrieve multiple objects in an array in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937620/query-to-retrieve-multiple-objects-in-an-array-in-mongodb)

i.e., 
Aggregation query  will have 4 pipeline operators:

```
  [match, unwind, match, group]
```

and then can be inserted to the other collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the data with **{"Grade": "First"}** either using aggregation or mongo query -

Aggregation query -

```
db.coll.aggregate([{'$match':{"Students.Grade":"First"}}, {$project: {"_id":1, "College_name":1}}])
```

Mongo Query -

```
db.coll.find({"Students.Grade":"First"}, {"College_name":1})
```

After that you can insert the data to other collection.

Comment: Yes this works. But i want to retrieve only the objects with {"Grade": "First"} where ("College_name" : "abcdef"). i.e., output should not contain the sub document with (name : "b").

Comment: Using $in and $ projection, we will get only the first matched element in the array. How would we get multiple matched elements??