# query to retrieve multiple objects in an array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have a array of objects as below.

```
"array" : [ 
    {
        "id" : 1
    }, 
    {
        "id" : 2
    }, 
    {
        "id" : 2
    }, 
    {
        "id" : 4
    }
]
```

If I want to retrieve multiple objects (**{id : 2}**) from this array, the aggregation query goes like this.

```
db.coll.aggregate([{ $match : {"_id" : ObjectId("5492690f72ae469b0e37b61c")}}, { $unwind : "$array"}, { $match : { "array.id" : 2}}, { $group : { _id : "$_id", array : { $push : { id : "$array.id"}}}}  ])
```

The output of above aggregation is

```
   {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5492690f72ae469b0e37b61c"),
        "array" : [ 
            {
                "id" : 2
            }, 
            {
                "id" : 2
            }
        ]
    }
```

Now the question is:
1) Is retrieving of **multiple objects** from an array possible using **find()** in MongoDB?

2) With respect to **performance**, is aggregation is the correct way to do? (Because we need to use **four pipeline operators**) ?

3) Can we use Java manipulation (looping the array and only keep {id : 2} objects) to do this after 
**find({"_id" : ObjectId("5492690f72ae469b0e37b61c")})** query? Because find will once retrieve the document and keeps it in RAM. But if we use aggregation four operations need to be performed in RAM to get the output.

Why I asked the 3) question is: Suppose if thousands of clients accessing at the same time, then RAM memory will be overloaded. If it is done using Java, less task on RAM.

4) **For how long the workingSet will be in RAM**??

Is my understanding correct???

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Please suggest me to have right insight on this..

Comment: 1 Question per Question. That's how this works. No there is no other way to filter an array using `.find()`. The aggregation framework is the tool for this. Please ask your other questions as separate questions. Question 4 belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: And pay attention to point "3" as if you are not aggregating anything or need this for some other later stage then you are likely better off filtering your arrays in the client. It all depends on scale.

Comment: Aggregation is slower than find(). This is the reason I asked question 3). So what would be right method. find()+Java or aggregation() ?

Comment: Of course aggregation is slower, you are manipulating the document which is why you are using it.  What I am saying is that if your only intent is to just filter out your matching `"id": 2` entries and the arrays are relatively small, then do it on the client after using `.find()` to retrieve the whole document.

Comment: The right method comes down to testing. We have no real understanding of whether this data is reuseable by other entities as such: whether or not storing it in RAM client side is useful. normally the aggregation framework is used to get a per connection view of the data that would be faster in the long run than doing it client side. remember that 4 operations in aggregation can also result in nearly 4 in client code, remember that the client needs to filter as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No. You project the first matching one with `$`, you project all of them, or you project none of them.
2. No-ish. If you have to work with this array, aggregation is what will allow you to extract multiple matching elements, but the correct solution, conceptually and for performance, is to design your document structure so this problem does not arise, or arises only for rare queries whose performance is not particularly important.
3. Yes.
4. We have no information that would allow us to give a reasonable answer to this question. This is also out of scope relative to the rest of the question and should be a separate question.