# Get Multiple Objects From Array in different Documents MongoDb

Tags: arrays, performance, mongodb

My collection coll is

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("566121aa4b88d840eb7d1c50"),
    "batchCourseId" : ObjectId("566122ab94b792fbdf81bcf3"),
    "array" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 4
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5661224a4b88d840eb7d1c51"),
    "batchCourseId" : ObjectId("566122ab94b792fbdf81bcf3"),
    "array" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 7
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 5
        }
    ]
}
```

what i need is to pull objects in array 'array' where 
batchCourseId = ObjectId("566122ab94b792fbdf81bcf3")

and  `2<array.id<=5`

expected output is

```
/* 1 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("566121aa4b88d840eb7d1c50"),
        "array" : [             
            {
                "id" : 3
            }, 
            {
                "id" : 4
            }
        ]
    }

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5661224a4b88d840eb7d1c51"),
    "array" : [            
        {
            "id" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 5
        }
    ]
}
```

already tried

```
db.coll.find({"batchCourseId" : ObjectId("566122ab94b792fbdf81bcf3")},
    { array: { $elemMatch: { id: { $gt: 2,$lte: 5} } } })
```

the output is like

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("566121aa4b88d840eb7d1c50"),
    "array" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 3
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5661224a4b88d840eb7d1c51"),
    "array" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 3
        }
    ]
}
```

close but only the first matching object in array is in result

FYI this only a sample set of data the original data is more complex and big in count

so pls let me know the best practice to do this, performance is also important

thanks in advance

Comment: This might help you: [query-to-retrieve-multiple-objects-in-an-array-in-mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937620/query-to-retrieve-multiple-objects-in-an-array-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation for achieving the same. A sample is shown below:

```
db.coll.aggregate(
  {$match: {"batchCourseId" : ObjectId("566122ab94b792fbdf81bcf3")}},
  {$unwind: '$array'},
  {$match: {'array.id': { $gt: 2,$lte: 5}}},
  {$group: {_id: '$_id', array: {$push : '$array'}}}
)
```

Result:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5661224a4b88d840eb7d1c51"), "array" : [ { "id" : 3 }, { "id" : 5 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("566121aa4b88d840eb7d1c50"), "array" : [ { "id" : 3 }, { "id" : 4 } ] }
```

Comment: already tried aggregate works for this but as i said this is a sample set not working in the original set  in that the array.id in int64/NumberLong() does that make any change the result is with all the array when did for the original data

Comment: worked for the original set with some small changes thanks Sarath Nair

Comment: @ArunRavindranath like what if I want to search for object which is in array with the help of its object id from search textfield? how will that work? Coz I have this issue going on with me. here is my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69233084/upon-pressing-search-button-does-not-give-the-result-of-searched-value-reac

Answer (score 2):

In MongoDB aggregation `$unwind` creates **[Cartesian_product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)** problem so in large data set is good way to avoid `$unwind`.

Let's check with your example if you use `$unwind` in `aggregation` then result looks like this

```js
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "batchCourseId": ObjectId("566122ab94b792fbdf81bcf3") }}, 
    { "$unwind": "$array" }
])
```

so result of above query is :

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("566121aa4b88d840eb7d1c50"), "batchCourseId" : ObjectId("566122ab94b792fbdf81bcf3"), "array" : { "id" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("566121aa4b88d840eb7d1c50"), "batchCourseId" : ObjectId("566122ab94b792fbdf81bcf3"), "array" : { "id" : 2 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("566121aa4b88d840eb7d1c50"), "batchCourseId" : ObjectId("566122ab94b792fbdf81bcf3"), "array" : { "id" : 3 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("566121aa4b88d840eb7d1c50"), "batchCourseId" : ObjectId("566122ab94b792fbdf81bcf3"), "array" : { "id" : 4 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5661224a4b88d840eb7d1c51"), "batchCourseId" : ObjectId("566122ab94b792fbdf81bcf3"), "array" : { "id" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5661224a4b88d840eb7d1c51"), "batchCourseId" : ObjectId("566122ab94b792fbdf81bcf3"), "array" : { "id" : 7 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5661224a4b88d840eb7d1c51"), "batchCourseId" : ObjectId("566122ab94b792fbdf81bcf3"), "array" : { "id" : 3 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5661224a4b88d840eb7d1c51"), "batchCourseId" : ObjectId("566122ab94b792fbdf81bcf3"), "array" : { "id" : 5 } }
```

this create multiple documents and in large documents in collections it slow the performance and increase processing time.

Instead of [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) use **[$map](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)** in aggregation with **[aggregation-set operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-set/)** and the query is as below :

```js
db.collection.aggregate([{
  "$match": {
    "batchCourseId": ObjectId("566122ab94b792fbdf81bcf3")
  }
}, {
  "$project": {
    "array": {
      "$setDifference": [{
          "$map": {
            "input": "$array",
            "as": "el",
            "in": {
              "$cond": {
                "if": {
                  "$and": [{
                    "$gt": ["$$el.id", 2]
                  }, {
                    "$lte": ["$$el.id", 5]
                  }]
                },
                "then": "$$el",
                "else": false
              }
            }
          }
        },
        [false]
      ]
    }
  }
}])
```